# Who is responsible for structuring teams in Scrum?

Tags: scrum

From Scrum Guide:

> Development Teams are structured and empowered by the **organization** to organize and manage their own work.

I am not a native English speaker and can not understand if by **organization** they mean **company**? If yes - then I don't get it. Why a company, not people themselves is responsible for selecting which people will go to which team? I thought Scrum is all about self-organization. Just tell people about a Product and they will organize themselves into teams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you just misread what is stated in that quote: Development teams are structured and empowered by the organization to manage their own work, e.g., the company 'structures' or 'puts in place' a team that is empowered to self-organize and structure *itself*.